# Show/Hide options in select based on previous selection

Tags: angularjs

There are several ship to addresses listed in the shipping address select field. UPS shipping options are listed in the shipper select field below it. There is also another shipping option that appeears, Local Van Delivery. This option should only
display if user chooses an address that contains "2200 W Apple Ave" in the "Street1" field.

I have read several topics in the AngularJS documentation,(ng-selected, select, ng-hide, ng-show, select, ng-value- ng-options) but not sure how to proceed. I am thoroughly confused. Any assistance is appreciated.

### SHIP ADDRESS SELECT

```
<div ng-show="shipaddresses" ng-class="{'view-form-select': !currentOrder.ShipAddressID, '': currentOrder.ShipAddressID }">
    <label ng-class="{required: !currentOrder.IsMultipleShip()}"
        ng-show="currentOrder.ShipAddressID || !currentOrder.IsMultipleShip()">
        {{('Shipping' | r) + ' ' + ('Address' | r) | xlat}}
    </label>
     <select class="form-control" name="shippingAddress"
          ng-change="setShipAddressAtOrderLevel()"
          ng-options="address.ID as address.AddressName for address in shipaddresses"
          ng-model="currentOrder.ShipAddressID"
          ng-required="!currentOrder.IsMultipleShip()">
            <option value=""></option>
      </select>
</div>
```

### SHIP TO ADDRESSEES JSON-->

```
 shipaddresses= [
{
"ID":"WHS",
"AddressName":"address1",
"Street1":"1940 W Elm",
"CompanyName":"warehouse"
},
{
"ID":"VAN",
"AddressName":"address2",
"Street1":"2200 W Apple Ave",
"CompanyName":"Main"
},
{
"ID":"CAB",
"AddressName":"address3",
"Street1":"2200 W Apple Ave",
"CompanyName":"CCO"
}
]
}
```

### SHIP METHOD SELECT -->

```
<div ng-show="user.ShipMethod != null && shippers"
     ng-class="{'view-form-select': !currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName,
                '': currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName }">
    <label ng-class="{required: !currentOrder.IsMultipleShip() && user.ShipMethod != null}"
            ng-show="currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName || !currentOrder.IsMultipleShip() &&
            user.ShipMethod != null">{{('Shipping' | r) + ' Method' | xlat}}
    </label>
    <select class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid"
            ng-change="updateShipper()" name="shipMethod"
            ng-model="currentOrder.LineItems[0].ShipperName"
            ng-show="user.ShipMethod.ShipperSelectionType ==  
              'UserDropDown'"
            ng-options="shipper.Name as (shipper.Name) for shipper in shippers"> 
        <!--="" --=""-->
        <option value="" class=""></option>
        <option value="0">LOCAL VAN DELIVERY</option>
        <option value="1">UPS Ground</option>
        <option value="2">UPS 3 Day Select</option>
        <option value="3">UPS 2nd Day Air</option>
        <option value="4">UPS 2nd Day Air AM</option>
        <option value="5">UPS Next Day Air Saver</option>
        <option value="6">UPS Next Day Air</option>
        <option value="7">UPS Next Day Air Early A.M.</option>
    </select>
</div>
```